# What's the best way (using jQuery) to implement buttons that increase and decrease the font-size of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have two buttons, one a decrease button and the other an increase button, that respectively decrease and increase the font-size of the whole page.

Say some `p` tags are set to 16px font, `h1` tags set to 30px, `li` tags to 14px, etc.

How do I, using jQuery, code the click function to increase their font-sizes. I'm also interested in making them only able to do it, say 5 times in either direction, to avoid absurd font-sizes.

I have something like this as is:

```
    $('button.decrease').click(function() {
        var fontSize = $('p').css('font-size');

        if (fontSize == "14px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '12px'
            });
        }
        else if (fontSize == "16px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '14px'
            });
        }
        else if (fontSize == "18px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '16px'
            });
        }
        else if (fontSize == "20px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '18px'
            });
        }
        else if (fontSize == "22px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '20px'
            });
        } 
    });

    $('button.increase').click(function() {
        var fontSize = $('p').css('font-size');

        if (fontSize == "12px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '14px'
            });
        }
        else if (fontSize == "14px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '16px'
            });
        }
        else if (fontSize == "16px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '18px'
            });
        }
        else if (fontSize == "18px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '20px'
            });
        }
        else if (fontSize == "20px") {
            $('p').css({
                'font-size': '22px'
            });
        }
    });
```

But it only works for increasing the size of the `p` tags, and I want it to be globally across the page.

Comment: Given that that functionality is already built-in to desktop browsers, why do you want to do it at all?

Comment: simpler if you just use `em` units in css and toggle a multiplication factor with your buttons on the body tag

Comment: If your page elements/css used relative font sizes (`em` or `%`), an increase or decrease would only need to modify one element - the root.

Comment: Why a hundred `if` statements? Can't you just do `$('p').css({ 'font-size': fontSize.replace('px','') + 2 +'px' });`. That'll save you a bunch of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a function to the `css` method.

```
$('#decrease').click(function() {
    $('p, h1, li').css('font-size', function(i, v) {
        return  +v.match(/\d+/).join() - 2
    })
})

$('#increase').click(function() {
    $('p, h1, li').css('font-size', function(i, v) {
        return  +v.match(/\d+/).join() + 2 
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s3TJr/

You can use universal selector `*` for selecting all the elements, but that's *overkill*.

Comment: uh that's a nice solution ^^

Comment: What does function(i, v) {} do?

Comment: @DougSmith In that function `i` is the index of selected elements, and `v` it's the current font-size value you can name them whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

this is an easy example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#inc').click(function() {

        $('*').each(function() {
            $(this).css('font-size', parseInt($(this).css('font-size').replace(/px$/,'')) + 2 + "px");
        });
    }) ;

    $('#dec').click(function() {

        $('*').each(function() {
            $(this).css('font-size', parseInt($(this).css('font-size').replace(/px$/,'')) - 2 + "px");
        });
    }) ;
});
```

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/YT8K4/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could do your font-size in em and than just change font size of your parent element e.g. body, like

```
<div class="small">
<div style="font-size: 1em;">
    Text 1
</div>

<div style="font-size: 1.5em;">
    Text 1.5
</div>

<div style="font-size: 0.5em;">
    Text 0.5
</div>
</div>
```

and your css:

```
.small {font-size: 0.85em;}
.big {font-size: 1.25em;}
```

once you change css class for parent element that will change the text size of your child elements, like this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsFWn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of CSS & JS? Load the page with a class of "100" on the  tag by default. JS could then be:

```
<html data-zoom=100>

----

[data-zoom="80"] h1,
[data-zoom="80"] p {
    font-size: 80%;
}

[data-zoom="120"] h1,
[data-zoom="120"] p {
    font-size: 120%;
}

----

<a href="#" class="-">-</a>
<a href="#" class="+">+</a>

----

var upDown = function () {
    var zoom = 100, zoomBy = 20;
    return function (e) {
        zoom = e.currentTarget.className === '-'? zoom - zoomBy : zoom + zoomBy;
        document.documentElement.dataset.zoom =  zoom;
    }
}();

$('.-, .\\+').on('click', upDown);
```

Check out http://jsbin.com/ehoyep/2/ for an example.